# PHP CURL give me 401 error but work fine on POSTMAN

Tags: php, curl

I am calling two API one login and second one for add user. To add user first i need to call login API then add user API. when i test these API in postman it work fine but when i call using CURL for  add user i am getting 401 error.

Login API in PostMan
[Login API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nktC.png)

Add User API in POSTMAN
[User API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYrpL.png)

login API PHP code which work fine

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://example.com/sapi/login?action=login",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "login=login&password=password",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

but when i call add user api with the following code it give me error.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://example.com/sapi/profile/generic?action=add",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 
    '{"data":{"user":{"generic":{"userid":"Hagrid","password":"abc123","firstname":"afds","lastname":"asf","useremail":"test@gmail.com"}}}}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/json"

  ),
));

 $response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: Simply, generate `CURL` request from `POSTMAN`

Comment: the curl request is generating 401 error

Comment: Http status `401` is an unauthorized error. Are you getting this for your login API?

Comment: No for login is ok.

Comment: the issue is fixed, i the add the userpassword in header and it working now

Comment: Because simply you haven't generated the CURL request from POSTMAN as I recommended to you.

Answer (score 0):

add the below code  before curl_exec

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "COOKIE.txt");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "COOKIE.txt");
```